# DataFrame GroupBy with Multiple Column Output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My goal is to take a DataFrame object and append multiple columns to it, where these columns are calculated by group, but these calculations are not intuitively vectorizable (they involve a cumulative sum with if statements).

I'm coming from an R data.table background, where I would run code that looks like:

```
DT[,c('newcol1','newcol2'):=f(.SD),by=groupvar]
```

where groupvar is the grouping variable, and function f takes in the sub-data.table (split by group) and returns a list with two arrays of length equal to that of the group. In this case, the side effect of the assignment := appends the two new columns newcol1 and newcol2 to the original data.table DT.

I've tried to use the pandas documentation but it's still a bit unclear to me how to replicate this operation (e.g. should my function f return DataFrames or just a dict with Series?).

Here's my initial df:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],'time':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],'choice':['a','a','b','a','b','b','b','b']})
```

I would like to add on two columns 'a' and 'b' such that they count the cumulative number of choices 'a' or 'b' by that id prior to that time period's choice. My desired output is this:

```
dffinal=pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],'time' [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],'choice':['a','a','b','a','b','b','b','b'],'a':[0,1,2,2,0,0,0,0],'b'=[0,0,0,1,0,1,2,3]})
```

I've written up a function that roughly does the correct operation by group (assuming it is already sorted by time):

```
def cumulativechoice(df):
    length=df.shape[0]
    cols=['a','b']
    for x in cols:
        df[x]=0
    for x in cols:
        counter=0
        for y in range(length):
            df.loc[y,x]=counter
            if df.loc[y,'choice']==x:
                counter=counter+1
    return df[cols]
```

The function works just fine if I run cumulativechoice(subdf) where subdf is the sub-DataFrame for one id, it breaks if I try df.groupby('id').apply(cumulativechoice) with error message 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
More generally, my question is not about the specifics of my function cumulativechoice, but what is the 'correct' split-apply-combine formula for where I want to 1) split by a group, 2) apply a function that generates multiple dicts/a DataFrame, etc. and 3) combines back so that the end result is I've added multiple columns to my output, in the particular case where's it's not as simple as a 'transform'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this is a bit involved, but not hard. You can leverage `pd.get_dummies` to make this simple.

```
df = df.set_index('id')

def f(x):
    return x.shift().fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)

v = pd.get_dummies(df.choice).groupby(level=0).apply(f)
pd.concat([v, df], 1).reset_index()

   id  a  b choice  time
0   1  0  0      a     1
1   1  1  0      a     2
2   1  2  0      b     3
3   1  2  1      a     4
4   2  0  0      b     1
5   2  0  1      b     2
6   2  0  2      b     3
7   2  0  3      b     4
```

---

**Details**

First, set the index.

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

Get OHEs from `get_dummies` -

```
i = pd.get_dummies(df.choice)
i

    a  b
id      
1   1  0
1   1  0
1   0  1
1   1  0
2   0  1
2   0  1
2   0  1
2   0  1
```

Now, `groupby` `ID`, `shift` each value by 1 down, find the cumsum and transform back.

```
v = i.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 
        x.shift().fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int))
v

    a  b
id      
1   0  0
1   1  0
1   2  0
1   2  1
2   0  0
2   0  1
2   0  2
2   0  3
```

Now, it's only a matter of concatenating the result -

```
pd.concat([v, df], 1)

    a  b choice  time
id                   
1   0  0      a     1
1   1  0      a     2
1   2  0      b     3
1   2  1      a     4
2   0  0      b     1
2   0  1      b     2
2   0  2      b     3
2   0  3      b     4
```

And reset the index after.

An alternative to concatenation would be slice assignment -

```
df[['a', 'b']] = v
df

   choice  time  a  b
id                   
1       a     1  0  0
1       a     2  1  0
1       b     3  2  0
1       a     4  2  1
2       b     1  0  0
2       b     2  0  1
2       b     3  0  2
2       b     4  0  3
```

Comment: This looks good and gives me what I want, but is there a way to do this without making a second DataFrame and manually concatenating it back (I don't know if this is actually possible, I'm just asking). Since I'm still learning pandas, is this method of making new columns and concatenating back the 'standard' split-apply-combine formula?

Comment: @Ray Yes, there is another way, which is cheaper. It is called slice assignment. Make sure to set the index to ID before doing anything (see edits to my answer). Furthermore, the S-A-C paradigm refers to splitting the dataframe into groups, operating on each group (hopefully vectorised), and then combining the results. More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is a bit of a dumb question, but in a general problem where I eventually want to add n new columns using a group-by operation (like this problem), what sort of object should my function f(x) that acts on the group output? Should it be a DataFrame, a dictionary with lists, etc.? I knew that in R if I output a data.frame style object (or the analogue of a python list) for each group it would 'stack' them for me over all of the groups in the final output, but what's the equivalent output I should aim for for each group when using pandas?

Comment: @Ray It depends on the function. For example, `apply` will pass a dataframe and expect a dataframe in return. `transform` will expect a Series. `agg` will expect a single value or a value that reduces from the input passed. Nothing but practice can help you understand what goes where.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `return df[cols]` to `return df`, prevents this error, but does not completely solve your problem. The `for-loop` you use in your code is not the appropriate way to iterate over a dataframe. Instead we can change this to `iterrows()` and eliminate useless code

```
def cumulativechoice(df):
    cols=['a','b']
    for z in cols:
        df[z]=0
    for x in cols:
        counter=0
        for index,row in df.iterrows(): 
            df.loc[index,x]=counter
            if row['choice']==x:
                counter=counter+1
    return df[cols] #<- this for just 'a' & 'b' or return df for entire df
```

However, maybe something like this will work a bit easier..

```
# set location where true == 1
df.loc[df.choice == 'a','a'] = 1
df.loc[df.choice == 'b','b'] = 1

#do a cumsum on new columns
df.fillna(0).groupby('id')['a','b'].cumsum()
```

gives you the values below, which start a 1 instead of zero, but you could offset that, if it is necessary....

```
  a  b
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  2  1
3  3  1
4  0  1
5  0  2
6  0  3
7  0  4
```

Comment: The output isn't exactly what I want, but that's not a big deal. My real issue involves the correct 'split-apply-combine' syntax/framework for these sorts of operations that involve adding multiple additional columns.